# Creating standalone tool-chain for android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg, java-native-interface

I am trying to build latest FFmpeg along with halfninja's code for android since some of the options are not available in older versions.I updated FFmpeg packages and tried to run **./create_toolchain.sh**.

I am getting the following error:

```
user@user:~/Android/android-ffmpeg-x264/Project/jni$ ./create_toolchain.sh 
    ~/Android/android-ffmpeg-x264/Project/jni ~/Android/android-ffmpeg-x264/Project/jni
    /home/user/android/tools:/home/user/android/platform-tools:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/user/android/tools:/home/user/android/platform-tools:/home/user/Android/android-ndk-r8e:/home/user/Android/android-ffmpeg-x264/Project/jni/toolchain/bin
    Host system 'linux-x86' is not supported by the source NDK!
    Try --system=<name> with one of:  linux-x86_64
```

My android NDK version is android-ndk-r8e.
I am facing problems in building latest version of FFmpeg by creating standalone toolchain.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try adding `--system=linux-x86_64` like it recommends?

Comment: Thanks jjiceman, i tried but it says no command found.

Comment: @vijay Did you find any solution?!

Answer (score 3):

Your system is 64 bit. The --system=linux-x86_64 should be the parameter of make-standalone-toolchain.sh which is part of the NDK. Like this:
$ANDROID_NDK/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh --system=linux-x86_64 ...

I don't know this create-toolchain.sh but I am sure there's an invocation to make-standalone-toolchain in it. That's where you have to add the parameter.